# Good data structure for storing agent path probabilities

Tags: python, json, data-structures

I'm working on an agent-based model where an agent can take different routes with a probability. For each route, there are multiple path points (i.e., `p1, p2, ..., p_end`). Currently, I am representing this as a JSON file like:

```
{    
   "paths": [
        {"[p3, p4, p_end]": 0.25},
        {"[p3, p2, p1, p_end]": 0.25},
        {"[p3, p4, p5, p7, p5, p_end]": 0.1},
        {"[p3, p4, p5, p7, p8, p5, p_end]": 0.1},
        {"[p3, p4, p5, p7, p10, p5, p_end]": 0.3}
    ]
}
```

Where each dictionary key is a route and its value is associated probability.

However, I have a lot more route options than this (i.e., 50-100) and I was wondering if there is a better way to represent this data structure for python instead of writing everything explicitly.

Sorry if this is a very basic question and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you assign a probability to each step (e.g. P{p_n -> p-2} = 0.3)? If so your data structure would be much simpler.

Comment: You seems to have loops in you path, like several p5 in the same path, is it intended ?

Comment: @Malo yes that is intended and thats why i need to mention whole path to refrain from infinite looping

Comment: @SalmanShaukat, ok so can you assign the probability to each small steps, like p3->p4 0.8 and p3->2 0.2 ? or is it mandatory to assign it to the whole path ?

Comment: @Malo Yes, I can do this step-by-step. One problem is: how to avoid loops when in certain cases E.g., P1 -> P2 & P2 -> P1 are allowed but something like P1 -> P2 -> P1 -> P1 should not be allowed. I guess I will use the "memory" concept by recording what states are already visited and consequently avoid loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the dictionary is good *at the end of the day*. If you can get the probabilities of going between any state, though, there are much better ways of representing it.

Your problem formulation resembles a basic Markov chain (if you're not familiar, it's a graph with probabilities for transitioning to different states). It sounds like it would be natural to represent the problem with a graph-like structure with weighted edges that show the probabilities.

With this, you could then use a basic graph traversal algorithm to construct a dictionary like the one you have above. Doing this offers a lot of benefits like being able to use Markov model analysis techniques and also being able to change the dictionary just by modifying the chain.

The paths would look something like this:

```
"paths": [ 
    {(1, 2): ?},
    {(1, 3): ?},
    ...
]
```

That's just a suggestion, though. The string-to-prob hash is probably the end-goal due to the sweet query efficiency.

**EDIT:**

Just noticed your follow-up question. I scraped together a quick function that you can of course optimize to your purposes. Let me know if I messed up somewhere (I think it's fine though).

For the following example, consider the chain:

[image]

The following process could be used assuming that the paths were taken in as an edge list.

```
# Very small set of edges. 
paths = {
    (1, 2) : 0.9,
    (1, 3) : 0.1,
    (2, 1) : 0.8,
    (2, 3) : 0.2,
}

from collections import defaultdict

# Make a simple dictionary to keep track of out paths
edge_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in paths.items():
    edge_dict[k[0]].append((k[1], v))
print(dict(edge_dict))
# > {1: [(2, 0.9), (3, 0.1)], 2: [(1, 0.8), (3, 0.2)]}

# Recursively construct a hash or probabilities
def dfs_from_state(start, edge_dict):
    path_hash = dict()
    dfs_from_state_recur(start, path_hash, edge_dict)
    return path_hash

def dfs_from_state_recur(state, path_hash, edge_dict, chain = [], prob = 1):
    if state not in edge_dict.keys(): 
        # If it's a terminal state, base case: hash the prob
        chain += [(state, )] 
        chain_str = "->".join([str(c[0]) for c in chain])
        path_hash[chain_str] = prob
        return 
    for adj, weight in edge_dict[state]:
        # Otherwise, dfs 
        link = (state, adj)
        if link not in chain: 
            dfs_from_state_recur(
                adj, path_hash, edge_dict, 
                chain+[link], prob*weight
            )


# Actually do DFS from every possible starting state
path_hash = dict()
for start in edge_dict.keys():
    path_hash.update(dfs_from_state(start, edge_dict))

[print("%12s : %0.4f" % e) for e in path_hash.items()]

#  1->2->1->3 : 0.0720
#     1->2->3 : 0.1800
#        1->3 : 0.1000
#  2->1->2->3 : 0.1440
#     2->1->3 : 0.0800
#        2->3 : 0.2000
```

Comment: I was also thinking about such a graph structure, the problem I had was: how to avoid loops when in certain cases E.g., P1 -> P2 & P2 -> P1 are allowed but something like P1 -> P2 -> P1 -> P1 should not be allowed. I guess I will use the "memory" concept by recording what states are already visited and consequently avoid loops.

Comment: @SalmanShaukat Please check out the update. Let me know if that was roughly what you wanted.